# Automatically Start an activity after boot

Tags: android

I am trying to launch and activity after boot.But app is getting crashed.

Its giving  error

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.example.shoky.onboot.OnBoot: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class

```
OnBoot.java

    package com.example.shoky.onboot;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;

    /**
     * Created by Shoky on 5/22/2016.
     */
    public class OnBoot extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context,Intent intent){
                Log.w("ASHOK","ONBOOT");
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(intent);

        }


    }



AndroidManifest.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.shoky.onboot" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <receiver android:name=".OnBoot"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name= "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

  </application>
</manifest>

MainActivity.java


    package com.example.shoky.onboot;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;


    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with changing this following in your manifest

```
<receiver
    android:name=".OnBoot"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>

</receiver>
```

Do something like this in your OnBoot class

```
public void onReceive(Context context,Intent intent){
    Log.w("ASHOK","ONBOOT");
    if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add `android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"`
   inside `receiver`.
2. Include "category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
   inside `intent filter`.

   ```
               <intent-filter>
                   <action android:name= "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
               </intent-filter>
           </receiver>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Inside onReceive method,
Intent reference(myIntent) you have created is different with what you are calling at startActivity(intent).

Note: intent provided by onReceive method is used to filter the action event with which it has been registered.
Eg:

```
if(intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"))
    { `enter code here`
      //code
    }
```